# How does DeltaSpike @Schedule wait finish before a new execution?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, schedule, deltaspike

I am using this lib [DeltaSpike Schedule](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/) to create cron tasks.

My task runs every minute, but I do not know how set Schedule to wait complete the old task.

```
@Scheduled(cronExpression = "0 * * * * ?")
public class WaiterRideTask implements Job {
}
```

If a task delays more than 1 minute, then other task is created yet.

Comment: I would inspect the Quartz-Documentation. DeltaSpike just delegates to org.quartz.Scheduler#scheduleJob. Quartz offers different annotations like @DisallowConcurrentExecution for your Job-Classes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dar Whi. This solved my problem: @DisallowConcurrentExecution